# What does "that being so" actually mean?

Tags: meaning

Here's an example from *Brisbane Times*,

> "What we do know is the world is more indebted now than it was before
>   the financial crisis." That being so, financial markets are seemingly
>   willing to disregard the flashpoints building up.

Answer (score 2):

It is a set phrase meaning:

[That being so](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/that+being+so):

> - accordingly, as a consequence, as a matter of course, as a result, as matters stand.

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the excerpt provided, *"That being so"* could be substituted for *"Assuming that to be the case"*.

In my interpretation, rather than affirming the preceding quoted statement, *"That being so"* is used to convey the author's perceived paradox that financial markets aren't as concerned about debt levels as he believes they should be, viz either:

- Financial markets are being irrational and ignoring the large level of global indebtedness;
- Or, that the mechanics of the markets have changed since the financial crisis, such that debt levels are no longer of concern.

However, the qualification *"the flashpoints building up"* suggests that the author believes the first point to be correct, and may be implying that markets will fall or correct in future.